# Solr dataimporthandler, unable to use entity timestamps

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I am using solr's data import handler to bring in data from several sources, using multiple entities.

When I run an import the dataimport.properties file has multiple timestamps for each individual entity.

I want to use those timestamps for each entities' delta query, I have tried dih.entityname.last_index_time to no avail.

How do I utilize the entity timestamps?

Comment: Use `dataimporter.<ENTITYNAME>.last_index_time` instead of `dih.<ENTITYNAME>.last_index_time`

Comment: @arun Tried this ${dataimporter.entityname.last_index_time} to no avail

Comment: Not sure if this one was created by you https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4788

Comment: @Jayendra Not my bug but thanks for the find

Answer (score 0):

Since SolR 1.4 there is custom entity last_index_time available.

Look at the **dataimport.properties** file in your core directory.

```
#Fri Dec 11 09:42:35 UTC 2015
core_1.last_index_time=2015-12-09 06\:00\:00
core_2.last_index_time=2015-12-09 06\:00\:00
last_index_time=2015-12-09 06\:00\:00
```

Last line is overall last_index_time value, 2nd & 3rd are entity-specific.

Your delta-query should look like:

```
deltaQuery="SELECT primary_id FROM test_table WHERE last_update &gt; '${dataimporter.test_1.last_index_time}'"
```

I already use this solution in my DataImport configuration - SolR 5.